# Regex to match numbers and commas, but not numbers starting with 0 unless it's 0,

Tags: regex

Well I tried to sum it up in the title.

I need a reg ex to match numbers and commas, but not numbers starting with 0 unless it's 0,number

My users enter hours in a field, so they have to be able to enter 0,3 hours, but they are not allowed to write 002 or 09.

I have this reg ex

```
^[0-9]*\,?[0-9]+$
```

How can I extend it to not allow start with 0 unless the 0 is followed by a comma

Comment: How many commas can there be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one :)

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*(|,\d+)|0,\d+)$
```

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work as intended. From chrome console `rx = /^(0|[1-9]\d*|\d+,\d+)$/
rx.test(03)
true`

Comment: Thank you sir. But it still gives me true on 03 and 00 `rx = /^(0|[1-9]\d*(|,\d+)|0,\d+)$/
/^(0|[1-9]\d*(|,\d+)|0,\d+)$/
rx.test(00)
true
rx.test(03)
true`

Comment: Because you testing an integer not a string. :)

Answer (score 2):

This one should suit your needs:

```
^0,\d*[1-9]|[1-9]\d*$
```

- either `0,\d*[1-9]`: a 0, followed by a comma, followed by 0 or more digit, followed by one digit between 1 and 9
- or `[1-9]\d*`: a digit between 1 and 9, followed by zero or more digit

Matches:

- 0,3
- 0,03
- 3
- 30

Doesn't match:

- 0
- 0,0
- 0,30
- 03

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work as intended. From chrome console `rx = /^0,\d*[1-9]|[1-9]\d*$/
rx.test(03)
true`

Comment: @AndreasLyngstad You have to test strings, not integers: `.test("03")` will print `false` `;)`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to force everything into a single regex to do this.

It will be far clearer if you use multiple regexes, each one making a specific check.

```
if ( /^[0-9]+,[0-9]+$/ || /^[1-9][0-9]*$/ )
```

Here we are making two different checks.  "Either this one matches, or the other one matches", and then you don't have to jam both conditions into one regex.

Let the expressive form of your host language be used, rather than trying to cram logic into a regex.